# Question about including author name in the content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using the following code to submit the abstract for the souvenir which we are preparing now.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,lipsum,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{transparent,rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\inst#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\address#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\email#1{\texttt{#1}}
\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}
 \makeatletter \renewcommand\@dotsep{300}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}

% % % % % % % %Abstract Environment % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
%\fi
\makeatother
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\faketableofcontents
\chapter{Abstracts}
\minitoc
\section{Type your title if the paper if  you are having Only one authors}

\aut{Name of the Author}\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics,}\\
\address{1st line, 2nd line, 3rd line}
             
\begin{abstract}       
       
       You can Type your Abstract Here.
       
\end{abstract}
\section{Type your Title here....}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\aut{First author }\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author@gmail.com}
\end{minipage} %
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\aut {Second Author,}\\
\inst{Department of Radiology}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author2@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}

\begin{abstract}
       
    
       You can Type your Abstract Here.
      
\end{abstract}


\section{Type your title of the paper if  you are having three authors}

\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut{First author }\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\aut {Second Author,}\\
\inst{Department of Radiology}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author2@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut {Third author}\\
\inst{Department of Mathematics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author3@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}

\begin{abstract}     
       
       You can Type your Abstract Here.
        
\end{abstract}



`\end{document}
```

The output is fine in the book but in the content if I use three authors, it coming one under one. But I want that author names must be in single line, irrespective of the number of authors I am using for a section.

> 1. Is there a way to correct this?
> 2. If there is any other solution to manage this situation, kindly provide.

I am giving my output for the convenience.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'souvenir'? I don't understand its use in this context.

Comment: @cfr Oh.I am sorry. Actually souvenir is a book usually published in  conferences which gives all the abstracts of the papers which are going to be presented in that conference.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what you mean. I just didn't know that's what they were called. (I wouldn't have known what to call one, to be honest.)

Answer (score 2):

A comma-separated list seems ideal for this purpose. This solution works by adding authors to a list as they are specified but writing the list to the contents only at the beginning of the abstract environment when all authors are (presumably) given.

Note that there were some spurious spaces causing overfull boxes in the template and I've removed these. Otherwise, the template for authors is the same.

When the new LaTeX 3 syntax, which I've used for the list, is active, spaces are ignored. So there is no need to comment ends of lines within the block of code within

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

in the preamble. Here the `~` actually produces a normal breakable space.

I've also replaced `\def` by `\newcommand` as this is much safer and removed the `\def`s which were doing nothing at all.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{expl3,minitoc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_souvenir_authors_clist

\newcommand\inst[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\address[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\email[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand\aut[1]{
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_souvenir_authors_clist {#1}
  \textbf{#1}
}
\newcommand\insti[1]{\textit{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}

\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{300}
\newenvironment{abstract}{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{\clist_use:Nnnn \g_souvenir_authors_clist {~and~} {,~} {~and~} }{}}
  \clist_gclear:N \g_souvenir_authors_clist
  \small
  \begin{center}
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}
  \end{center}
  \quotation}
{\endquotation}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\faketableofcontents
\chapter{Abstracts}
\minitoc
\section{Type your title if the paper if  you are having Only one authors}

\aut{Name of the Author}\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics,}\\
\address{1st line, 2nd line, 3rd line}

\begin{abstract}

       You can Type your Abstract Here.

\end{abstract}

\section{Type your Title here....}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\aut{First author }\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\aut {Second Author}\\
\inst{Department of Radiology}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author2@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}

\begin{abstract}

       You can Type your Abstract Here.

\end{abstract}

\section{Type your title of the paper if you are having three authors}

\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut{First author }\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\aut {Second Author}\\
\inst{Department of Radiology}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author2@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut {Third author}\\
\inst{Department of Mathematics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author3@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}

\begin{abstract}

       You can Type your Abstract Here.

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]